# Why can't I boot into Ubuntu installed alongside Windows 8?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, startup, windows-8

Once I reboot it after the installation, it brings me to a screen to choose Windows 8 or Ubuntu. When I click Ubuntu it brings me to a screen with this options:

1. Reinstall windows
2. Change the language or
3. Repair

And then it brings me back to the GRUB, and then if I pick Ubuntu it does it again.

Comment: Do you mean after the installation of Ubuntu, isn't?

Comment: Insert your live CD and do the repair.

Answer (score 1):

Pre install windows 8 comes with UEFI secure boot enabled 
(UEFI which substitutes what we have known as the BIOS)
which prevent unrecognized source to boot or Linux

But latest version of Ubuntu have support for the UEFI boot see (you doesn't mention which Ubuntu version you are using) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

So there is no problem in dual boot Ubuntu with windows 8

for your convenient (solve your problem ) you can off the UEFI secure boot in some easy step they are

**1** ) while **holding shift key click on restart** option (from power)

**2** ) windows will show you option then select **Troubleshoot**

**3** ) select **advanced options**

**4** ) select **UEFI frameware settings** then disable it after restart

[Here is the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElzvaL96cw0)

Then you are able to boot ubuntu and even old version of the Linux which couldn’t install before in windows 8 .

in dual boot if you don’t get the windows 8 listed in grub menu then

type following command in terminal while mounting drive which have windows installed

> sudo update-grub2